# PINE: Why trailing stop loss activates at each bar?

Tags: pine-script

Here is a simple strategy that I am implementing:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © me
//@version=5
strategy("Just Trend", process_orders_on_close=true, overlay=true, initial_capital=50, default_qty_value = 14, currency='USDT', default_qty_type=strategy.cash, calc_on_every_tick = false, max_labels_count=500)
backtestStartDate = input.time(timestamp("31 Jan 2023"), title="Start Date", group="Backtest Time Period")
backtestEndDate = input.time(timestamp("27 Mar 2023"), title="End Date", group="Backtest Time Period")




// ### Four Smoothed Moving Averages

len1 = 21
//input(21, minval=1, title="Length 1", group = "Smoothed MA Inputs")
src1 = close
//input(close, title="Source 1", group = "Smoothed MA Inputs")
smma1 = 0.0
sma_1 = ta.sma(src1, len1)
smma1 := na(smma1[1]) ? sma_1 : (smma1[1] * (len1 - 1) + src1) / len1
plot(smma1, color=color.white, linewidth=2, title="21 SMMA")

len2 = 50
//input(50, minval=1, title="Length 2", group = "Smoothed MA Inputs")
src2 = close
//input(close, title="Source 2", group = "Smoothed MA Inputs")
smma2 = 0.0
sma_2 = ta.sma(src2, len2)
smma2 := na(smma2[1]) ? sma_2 : (smma2[1] * (len2 - 1) + src2) / len2
plot(smma2, color=color.new(#6aff00,0), linewidth=2, title="50 SMMA")

h100 = input.bool(title="Show 100 Line", defval=true, group = "Smoothed MA Inputs")
len3 = 100
//input(100, minval=1, title="Length 3", group = "Smoothed MA Inputs")
src3 = close
//input(close, title="Source 3", group = "Smoothed MA Inputs")
smma3 = 0.0
sma_3 = ta.sma(src3, len3)
smma3 := na(smma3[1]) ? sma_3 : (smma3[1] * (len3 - 1) + src3) / len3
sma3plot = plot(h100 ? smma3 : na, color=color.new(color.yellow,0), linewidth=2, title="100 SMMA")

len4 = 200
//input(200, minval=1, title="Length 4", group = "Smoothed MA Inputs")
src4 = close
//input(close, title="Source 4", group = "Smoothed MA Inputs")
smma4 = 0.0
sma_4 = ta.sma(src4, len4)
smma4 := na(smma4[1]) ? sma_4 : (smma4[1] * (len4 - 1) + src4) / len4
sma4plot = plot(smma4, color=color.new(#ff0500,0), linewidth=2, title="200 SMMA")

// Trend Fill

trendFill = input.bool(title="Show Trend Fill", defval=true, group = "Smoothed MA Inputs") 
ema2 = ta.ema(close, 2)
ema2plot = plot(ema2, color=color.new(#2ecc71, 50), style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, title="EMA(2)", editable = false)

bool condBuy = (ema2 > smma4 and trendFill) and close > smma1 and smma1 > smma2 and smma2 > smma3 and smma3 > smma4

bool condSell = close < smma1 or close < smma2 or close < smma3 or close < smma4


fill(ema2plot, sma4plot, color=  ema2 > smma4 and trendFill ? color.new(color.green, 50) : ema2 < smma4 and trendFill ? color.new(color.red, 50) : na, title = "Trend Fill")

// End ###



inTradeWindow = time > backtestStartDate and time <= backtestEndDate

leverage = input.int(125, title='Leverage',minval = 1, maxval = 300 ,step = 1)

precision = input.int(1, title='Precision')

bool inLong = false



var table tabb = table.new(position.top_center, 4, 3)

print(txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4) =>
    
    table.cell(tabb, 0, 0, str.tostring(txt1), bgcolor = color.green)
    table.cell(tabb, 1, 0, str.tostring(txt2), bgcolor = color.orange)
    table.cell(tabb, 2, 0, str.tostring(txt3), bgcolor = color.blue)
    table.cell(tabb, 3, 0, str.tostring(txt4), bgcolor = color.yellow)
   


//print(last_bar_index,last_bar_index,last_bar_index,last_bar_index)

RoundDown(number, decimals) =>
    factor = math.pow(10, decimals)
    math.floor(number * factor) / factor



transactionQty = math.max(RoundDown(14 * leverage  / close, 2), 0)



// LONG TRADES
if inTradeWindow and condBuy and strategy.opentrades > 0 == false // and not inLong[1] // 
    strategy.entry("Enter Long", strategy.long, qty=transactionQty)
    strategy.exit("Exit Long", from_entry="Enter Long", trail_points=500, trail_offset=500)

    inLong:=true
    
if bar_index % 2 == 0 and inTradeWindow
    a = str.tostring(strategy.opentrades)
    label.new(bar_index, na, a, yloc = yloc.abovebar, size = size.normal,textcolor = color.white)
```

But when I test it, you see that an entry order and a corresponding exit order are executed **on every bar** whereas I want the stop loss to work and in particular the trail_points and trail_offset  (I have set them on big values, 500, just to show, that they don't seem to have any effect):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

500 ticks for BTCUSD is a 0.01 * 500 = 5$  (syminfo.mintick * 500), and within one bar price changes more than that. So you need to increase `trail_points`, or use real price values with `trail_price` parameter in `strategy.exit()` funcion.